# Number format not getting applied in Excel

Tags: visualforce, excel

I am generating Excel from Visualforce by xml format.
When I add number type Instead of String It doesnt allow me to open excel.

Any reason why? Whats alternate solution for this?

```
<Data ss:Type="Number">
    {!mw.avgMonthBudgt}
</Data>
```

Comment: mentioned code is Visualforce component?

Comment: Its directly written in VF page